# MongoDB ETIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ok i dont know what is going on here i have 2 working project and some backup project. Which were working before and is **working online right now in Heroku**.
Today i try to do the normal routine and started node, and now i am getting this error below. I though it might be that i just recently install team-view and that might affect it. But this doesn't seem to be the case because i tried it on a different computer and i get the same error. I have no clue to how to debug this, can someone help me please!!

[image]

Comment: Your [mongoDB instance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) is not started. [Start](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-the-mongodb-service) (or [install](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb) then start) the MongoDB service.

Comment: I never use to have to start or install mongo before, why do i have to do this? net start MongoDB service name is invalid

Comment: Oh by the way i am connecting it through mongolab, i dont have a local database store in my computer

Comment: Maybe your mongolab instance is not accessible from your PC. Check connectivity and your configuration files.

Comment: So did you find a solution to this problem after all? And what was it?

Answer (score 0):

Change you connection string to

```
variable = 'mongodb://username:xxx@clusternamecluster-shard-00-00-i548w.mongodb.net:27017,developerbookcluster-shard-00-01-i548w.mongodb.net:27017,developerbookcluster-shard-00-02-i548w.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=DeveloperBookCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your question so that it contains a bit more explanation what you do and why, plus how it relates to the question.