# I have been trying to connect my node to MongoDB and I have been getting errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have done created a user and password on my mongoDB and I have written the code for connection in the NodeJS but I keep getting error everytime I console.log my result to the Node JS server.

I have gone to change my password on the Atlas backend but still not working

```
    const mongodb = require('mongodb');
    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


    const mongoConnect = callback =>{
        MongoClient.connect(
            'mongodb+srv://Olumide:84NZWm15WHH4JOP4@cluster0- 
   alft3.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
             )
                 .then(client =>{
         console.log('Connected!!!');
         callback(client);
     }).catch(err =>{
         console.log(err);
     });
    }

 module.exports = mongoConnect;
```

> [nodemon] 1.19.0 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>   [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
>   (node:12248) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   { Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-alft3.mongodb.net
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:197:19)   errno: 'ETIMEOUT',   code: 'ETIMEOUT',   syscall: 'querySrv',   hostname:
>   '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-alft3.mongodb.net' } [nodemon] clean exit -
>   waiting for changes before restart

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the warning is:

```
MongoClient.connect('<connection_string>', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

about `ETIMEOUT` error, is due to a mongo service issue (see [MongoDB ETIMEOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813185/mongodb-etimeout)) or a remote machine issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, it have fixed it, it was my IP Whitelist that I had to reset to the current one